# "android.hardware.camera is deprecated" : Can I import the source to project directory?

Tags: android, android-camera

It is known that android.hardware.camera is deprecated and no longer available for new versions. What if I want to use it rather than going for new camera api? Is there a way to import the source code of the same to my local project directory?

Answer (score 0):

> What if I want to use it rather than going for new camera api?

Just use it. "Deprecated" means "we have something else that we recommend that you use". In this case, the original Camera API is still there, and it is your only option on API Level 19 and older.

Just bear in mind that manufacturer support for the Camera API will decline steadily over time, just because probably they won't spend as much engineering and Q&A time on it. By 2018, when Android 5.0+ has 90+% of the market, apps should be using the new `camera2` API pretty much exclusively.

> Is there a way to import the source code of the same to my local project directory?

No, and you don't need it, as it is part of the Android SDK, the same as everything else in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If your device does not support the old interface, you have no choice but work with camera2, because these two APIs are based on completely different hardware abstraction level (HAL) and cannot be cross-ported to the other. This is why the new non-backward-compatible API was introduced.

Comment: If the *device* didn't support the old interface, older apps would fail to work. The point of deprecation is to give developers time to move to the new API before the old one is dropped.